# convert PIL Image to numpy array sometimes don't work

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have this block of code to open an image and convert it to gray scale:

```
with Image.open(file_path).convert(mode='L') as image:
    ...
    block = image.crop((start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y))
    art[row] += tslt_block(block)
```

where `tslt_block()` is defined as follows:

```
def tslt_block(img):
    char_table = "$@B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwmZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft/\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!lI;:,\"^`'. "
 -> a = np.array(img)
    gray_scale = a.mean()
    return char_table[int(gray_scale / 255 * (len(char_table) - 1))]
```

the problem is, the line marked by an arrow(`a = np.array(img)`) seems to have no effect! After this line was executed `a` is the same object as `img`:
[image]

This is pretty weird since this code should translate the image to a numpy array, as shown in the following console session:
[image]

I can't understand this! Why the same line of code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't?

**update:**
It seems that converting the whole image works, but converting a crop doesn't:
[image]
[image]

My complete code is:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import math, os

scale = 0.43


def tslt_block(img):
    char_table = "$@B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwmZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft/\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!lI;:,\"^`'. "
    a = np.array(img)
    gray_scale = a.mean()
    return char_table[int(gray_scale / 255 * (len(char_table) - 1))]


def main():
    file_path = input('input full file path: ')
    base_name, *_ = os.path.splitext(file_path)
    output_file_path = base_name + '.txt'
    columns = int(input('input number of columns: '))

    with Image.open(file_path).convert(mode='L') as image:
        width, height = image.size
        block_width = width / columns
        block_height = block_width / scale
        rows = math.ceil(height / block_height)
        art = []
        for row in range(rows):
            art.append('')
            for column in range(columns):
                start_x, start_y = column * block_width, row * block_height
                end_x = int(start_x + block_width if start_x + block_width < width else width)
                end_y = int(start_y + block_height if start_y + block_height < height else height)
                block = image.crop((start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y))
                art[row] += tslt_block(block)

    with open(output_file_path, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write('\n'.join(art))
        print('output written to {}'.format(output_file_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the image I'm using for testing is:
[image: python logo 600*600]

Comment: Do you have an image which is able to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @Suever Yes. I've updated my post and uploaded the image.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've solved my own problem. it seems that if start_x and start_y are `float`, then changing the cropped image to a numpy array won't work. If I convert them into `int`, it works. But I still wonder why. Is there a bug in Pillow or numpy?

Comment: The bug is in your code.  `block_width = width / columns` sets `block_width` to a float.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp Why can't I convert a cropped image to numpy array if I use floats as coordinates? When I cropped the image, there were no exceptions.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to use floating point numbers for coordinates in numpy.  For example, `a[2.5]` makes no sense at all.  What is it even supposed to mean?  Why would they have a special case for `a[2.0]`?